# KIVY ERROR: AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'

Tags: python, class, kivy, kivy-language, super

i am new to this kind of programming and i am trying to solve this error (python 3, run on PyCharm):

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 860, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 KeyError: 'lista'
 
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/...PycharmProjects/RUBRICA/main.py", line 62, in <module>
     application.run()
   File "C:\...AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 829, in run
     root = self.build()
   File "C:/...PycharmProjects/RUBRICA/main.py", line 57, in build
     self.screens[0].ids.lista.data = [{'text='+ str(x)} for x in range(30)]
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 863, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

##########PY FILE:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout

import os

os.chdir("C:\\Users\\Davide\\PycharmProjects\\RUBRICA")
first_imp = False

class Introduction1Window(Screen):
    def go_to_int2(self):
        application.sm.current = application.screens[2].name

class Introduction2Window(Screen):
    file_chooser: ObjectProperty(None)
    dir = "C:\\Program Files"

    def go_to_main(self):
        application.sm.switch_to(application.screens[0])
    def set_dir(self):
        self.dir = self.file_chooser.path

class NewContact(Screen):
    pass

class ModContact(Screen):
    pass

class MainWindow(Screen):
    lista = ObjectProperty(None)
    def set_data(self):
        self.lista.data = [{'text='+ str(x)} for x in range(30)]
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class Main(App):
    sm = None
    screens = [MainWindow(name="MainWindow"),Introduction1Window(name="Introduction1Window"),Introduction2Window(name="Introduction2Window")]

    def build(self):
        self.sm = WindowManager()
        self.icon = 'intbackgorund.png'
        for screen in self.screens:
            self.sm.add_widget(screen)
        if first_imp:
            self.sm.current = "Introduction1Window"
        else:
            self.sm.current = "MainWindow"
        #self.screens[0].ids.lista.data = [{'text='+ str(x)} for x in range(30)]
        return self.sm.current


application = Main()
application.run()
```

*All the parts that are not useful for the actual state of the programme will be used in the future in this project*

#######KIVY FILE

```
<MainWindow>:
    lista: lista
    orientation: "vertical"
    on_enter: root.set_data()
    Label:
        text: "main"
    RecycleView:
        viewclass: 'Button'
        RecycleBoxLayout:
            id: lista
            default_size: None, dp(56)
            default_size_hint: 1, None
            orientation: 'vertical'
```

If someone could explain this problem I would be very greateful.

Answer (score 0):

Several problems:

- Your `lista` Property is attached to the wrong item in your `kv`. It should be attached to the `RecycleView`, not the `RecycleBoxLayout`.
- You must include a `height` property for the `RecycleBoxLayout`.

Here is an updated version of your `kv`:

```
<MainWindow>:
    lista: lista
    on_enter: root.set_data()
    Label:
        text: "main"
    RecycleView:
        id: lista
        viewclass: 'Button'
        RecycleBoxLayout:
            default_size: None, dp(56)
            default_size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            orientation: 'vertical'
```

- Your construction of the `data` property is incorrect. You should be creating a list of dictionaries, but you are creating a list of sets (each containing one string).

Here is a corrected version of your `data` construction:

```
class MainWindow(Screen):
    lista = ObjectProperty(None)
    def set_data(self, *args):
        self.lista.data = [{'text': str(x)} for x in range(30)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This didn't work completely, in fact I get this error now:

```
Exception: Invalid instance in App.root
```

this is the updated code:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout

import os

os.chdir("C:\\Users\\Davide\\PycharmProjects\\RUBRICA")
first_imp = False

class Introduction1Window(Screen):

    def go_to_int2(self):
        application.sm.current = application.screens[2].name


class Introduction2Window(Screen):
    file_chooser: ObjectProperty(None)
    dir = "C:\\Program Files"

    def go_to_main(self):
        application.sm.switch_to(application.screens[0])
    def set_dir(self):
        self.dir = self.file_chooser.path

#class NewContact(Screen):
    #pass

#class ModContact(Screen):
    #àpass

class MainWindow(Screen):
    lista = ObjectProperty(None)

    def set_data(self,*args):
        self.lista.data = [{'text=': str(x)} for x in range(30)]


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class Main(App):
    sm = None
    screens = [MainWindow(name="MainWindow"),Introduction1Window(name="Introduction1Window"),Introduction2Window(name="Introduction2Window")]

    def build(self):
        self.sm = WindowManager()
        for screen in self.screens:
            self.sm.add_widget(screen)
        if first_imp:
            self.sm.current = "Introduction1Window"
        else:
            self.sm.current = "MainWindow"
        return self.sm.current



application = Main()
application.run()
```

KIVY FILE:

```
<MainWindow>:
    lista: lista
    on_enter: root.set_data()
    Label:
        text: "main"
    RecycleView:
        id: lista
        viewclass: 'Button'
        RecycleBoxLayout:
            default_size: None, dp(56)
            default_size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            orientation: 'vertical'
```